# Flight from Singapore to Kochi via Bangalore, where will we need to do customs and reclaim our baggage?

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, luggage, connecting-flights, air-india

We fly From Singapore to Kochi (flight nr:  IX -485) on a joined ticket (Indian Airlines/[Air India Express](https://www.airindiaexpress.in/en)) with checked-in baggage. 
[image]

Connecting flight is in Bengaluru (SIN 21:10 -> BLR 23:15, **Only one hour for connection** BLR 00:15 -> COK 01:30 )

Will we go through customs in BLR or in COK, will we need to reclaim our check-in baggage and then go to the gate?

Comment: With Joined ticket do you mean that it's a single ticket under one PNR?

Comment: @ArpitBajpai Hi, yes precisely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as @Arpit Bajpai suggested I have got in touch with Air India Express in regards to Bangalore stop... below is their answer.

> Kindly note that as you flying with Air India Express from SIN-COK via BLR in the same aircraft, you do not require to not re-board your flight at your connecting point. You will board in a your at your Origin (SIN) and complete the remaining formalities at your Destination (COK)

**TLDR;** we do not leave the plane and disembark only in Kochi.

Answer (score 0):

Your first port of arrival is Bangalore so it is certain that the immigration and customs check should take place in Bangalore if you go by the standards. However, Air India does provide you with the facility of doing the formalities at the last port of arrival based on the route you are taking.

You can find the details on [Air India website](http://www.airindia.in/Transit-Information.htm).

In a nutshell, if your flight number is in the range of AI010 – AI399 or AI900 to AI999 then Your baggage would be tagged to the final destination and you can do the formalities in Cochin instead of Bangalore.

Comment: Hi Arpit, my flight number is IX -485 company is `air India express`, I have updated question with logo

Comment: In that case, your best bet is to call them. I am not aware of Air India Express policies and I can't seem to find the information online.

Answer (score -1):

Your port of arrival is Bengaluru, and hence the place for immigration check. The customs will thus apply at the port of entry.

And since there would be a custom check, you will have to claim your checked-in luggage, go through the customs, and go to the domestic terminal of Bengaluru airport, visit the counter of Air India and submit your luggage there.

Having just one hour for connection is very little, which leaves no room for any delay. And with Air India, I am sorry to say, [delays are likely to happen](https://qz.com/india/1215471/delayed-air-india-has-the-worst-on-time-performance-of-indian-airliners/). A usual immigration line takes about 15-20 minutes for Indian citizens and 5-10 minutes for foreigners. If you don't have anything to declare at the customs, that would just mean passing through the green channel. If you do have however, that is bound to consume way more time. And these apply to both foreign and Indian nationals.

Also note that domestic flight travels in India do not allow any liquids to be carried in hand-luggage. So any of those bottles duty-free perfumes/liquor or the like will need to be stored in your check-in luggage when you do the transfer.

Reference: [Mumbai airport customs](https://csia.in/passenger/customs-on-arrival.aspx) but the rules are very similar across all international airports in India